# Find all combination that sum to N with multiple lists

Tags: python, numpy

**Given**:

- `m` number of lists (`m` can vary).
- Each list contain `arange()` of numbers.

**Want**:

- Find the m-tuple (one number per list) that `sum()` to `N`.

**What I have**:

- I can find all combination in a static number of lists.

  ```
  import numpy as np
  for a in np.arange(0,1,0.01):
      for b in np.arange(0,1,0.01):
          for c in np.arange(0,1,0.01):
              for d in np.arange(0,1,0.01):
                  if (a+b+c+d) == 1.0: 
                      print a,b,c,d
  ```

I would also like to find an optimal way to compute this as well.

Comment: A naive approach could use https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product to give you the nested-for-loop behaviour for any number of lists.

Comment: Can the lists differ, like your "Given:" suggests, or are they all the same, like your example suggests? Which is it?

Comment: And are you really sure you want to add floats and test for exact equality?

Comment: Yes, every range is the same. And yes, they must be floats.

Comment: @StefanPochmann is right - you do not want to be testing exact equality between floats because of rounding error. For example, you could use integers between 0 and 99 and test whether they sum to 100.

Comment: Also, testing every possible combination of 4 elements is very inefficient. *Hint*: you can rule out many combinations at once if the first 2 or 3 elements already sum to a value greater than 1.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea to approach it. I will try that.

Comment: @drum That just depends on how big your ranges are - you can use `range(N)`, test whether the elements sum to `N`, then divide by `N` afterwards to get floats between 0 and 1. Furthermore, summation is commutative, so the order of `a, b, c, d` do not matter. For example you could do `for a in range(N): ... for b in range(a, N): ... for c in range(b, N): ...` etc. to avoid testing different permutations of the same 4 values.

Comment: Just to be sure: You know that for example `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is **False**, right?

Comment: I guess I should edit my question. It's actually permutation since  `a,b,c,d` do matter. But I guess once I find the combination that sums up to `N`, then I can permute over the results.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Why is that False? I did a test using my original code above and it did return the correct numbers.

Comment: It's False because floats aren't exact and you can get unlucky. The `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` example is one where they "fail". So are you still sure you want to do this?

Comment: Guess not. I will go integers for the look-up and summation, then convert to float.

Comment: None of 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 are represented exactly, btw. You can see the exact represented value with `'%.70f' % 0.1`, for example, which shows 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625000000000000000.

Comment: If you do go with integers, I think I have a neat solution.

Comment: Thank you. And coupled with @Mijamo's solution, my code ran a lot faster too.

Comment: I wonder if you could create an equation using combination math to get the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the ranges are all the same and we ought to use integers. Here's an imho neat way then.

Instead of producing four numbers and testing whether they add up to 10, produce **three** numbers defining a partition of the interval [0, 10] into four intervals. For example when we have the cuts at (3, 4, 8), and we add the end points 0 and 10, then we have the boundaries (0, 3, 4, 8, 10). The differences between adjacent boundaries are (3-0, 4-3, 8-4, 10-8) = (3, 1, 4, 2). That's four numbers adding up to 10. Here's code doing that:

```
n = 10
import itertools, operator
for cuts in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(n+1), 3):
    combi = list(map(operator.sub, cuts + (n,), (0,) + cuts))
    if max(combi) < n:
        print(combi)
```

That prints:

```
[0, 0, 1, 9]
[0, 0, 2, 8]
[0, 0, 3, 7]
[0, 0, 4, 6]
[0, 0, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 6, 4]
[0, 0, 7, 3]
[0, 0, 8, 2]
[0, 0, 9, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 9]
[0, 1, 1, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 7]
...
...
[7, 2, 0, 1]
[7, 2, 1, 0]
[7, 3, 0, 0]
[8, 0, 0, 2]
[8, 0, 1, 1]
[8, 0, 2, 0]
[8, 1, 0, 1]
[8, 1, 1, 0]
[8, 2, 0, 0]
[9, 0, 0, 1]
[9, 0, 1, 0]
[9, 1, 0, 0]
```

It's very efficient, since it produces the combinations pretty directly. The `if max(combi) < n` only filters out `[0, 0, 0, 10]`, `[0, 0, 10, 0]`, `[0, 10, 0, 0]` and `[10, 0, 0, 0]`.

---

Here's a speed comparison between your original, mine, and @Mijamo's, with a range of 100 numbers like in your example:

```
  drum: 21.027 seconds
Stefan:  0.708 seconds
Mijamo: 62.864 seconds
```

Full code for that test:

```
import itertools, operator
from timeit import timeit

def drum(n):
    out = []
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(n):
            for c in range(n):
                for d in range(n):
                    if a + b + c + d == n:
                        out.append((a, b, c, d))
    return out

def Stefan(n):
    combinations = (map(operator.sub, cuts + (n,), (0,) + cuts)
                    for cuts in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(n+1), 3))
    return [c for c in combinations if max(c) < n]

def Mijamo(n):
    combinations = itertools.product(range(n), repeat=4)
    return [tuple for tuple in combinations if sum(tuple) == n]

for func in drum, Stefan, Mijamo:
    print '%6s: %6.3f seconds' % (func.__name__, timeit(lambda: func(100), number=1))
```

Comment: Actually, there is nothing wrong with having `[10, 0, 0, 0]`. It is a valid result.

Comment: Can you please explain what `(map(operator.sub, cuts + (n,), (0,) + cuts)` does? It's kind of confusing.

Comment: Well, your original wants sum 1 and your a/b/c/d come from the range [0, ..., 0.99]. So when I go for sum 10, my numbers should only come from [0, ..., 9], no?

Comment: Oh wow. You a right. That's actually a bug in my code since I completely forgot range is [..)

Comment: That `map(operator.sub, ...)`: For example when we have the cuts (3, 7, 8), and we add the end points 0 and 10, then we have the boundaries (0, 3, 7, 8, 10). The differences between adjacent boundaries are (3-0, 7-3, 8-7, 10-8) = (3, 4, 1, 2). Clear enough?

Comment: That's amazing! I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: have exact same problem and I am struggling. can someone please write this logic in Java

Comment: Just to clarify (many years later) we're arbitrarily doing the problem for m = 4 here? Can we confirm this can be smoothly parametised and whether it breaks down < 3?

Answer (score 2):

All the combinations can be retrieved this way:

```
combinations = itertools.product(np.arange(0,1,0.01), repeat = m)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

And as it is a generator, you can then make a new generator to return the tupples that sum to n this way

```
results = (tuple for tuple in combinations if sum(tuple) == N)
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using "product" from itertools to get all possible m-length tuples. Then you just filter by the condition that the tuple sum == N