# Find all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum without a given set of numbers (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, combinations

How would you find all the integer(excluding negative) combinations of a given number without a given set of numbers?
I would imagine it most similar to finding solutions to a [stars and bars](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_stars-and-bars.html) problem.

For example,

- Find all combinations of 3 numbers that sum to 3
- Result: (0,0,3) (0,1,2) (0,2,1) (0,3,0) (1,0,2) (1,1,1) (1,2,0) (2,0,1) (2,1,0) (3,0,0)

I found something similar implemented in Python. Is it possible to do this in Java?
[General bars and stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965734/general-bars-and-stars)

Comment: `(0,0,3)` and `(3,0,0)` are same combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all possible combinations of `n` positive numbers with the sum of `target` using `Stack` and recursion

```
public class Test {
    private static final int n = 3;
    private static final int target = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> terms = new Stack<>();

        sums(terms, 0);
    }

    public static void sums(Stack<Integer> terms, int curSum) {
        if(terms.size() == n - 1) {
            terms.add(target - curSum);
            System.out.println(terms);
            terms.pop();
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= target - curSum; i++) {
            terms.add(i);
            sums(terms, curSum + i);
            terms.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
[0, 0, 3]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 3, 0]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 0]
[3, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Have a look at this one: [Find all combination that sum to N with multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970848/find-all-combination-that-sum-to-n-with-multiple-lists/34971783#34971783)